# Disable Button click sound in android

Tags: android

How to disable click sound of a particular button in Android app?

Here is my code:

```
more1after.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sc.scrollTo(sc.getScrollX() + 75,
                sc.getScrollY() + sc.getWidth() + 5);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Isn't it disabled by default!!

Comment: No it was enabled by default

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Try this code for disable button click sound effect:

```
yourbutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

(or) Layout XML file

```
 <Button... android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: setSoundEffectsEnabled i have set it to false on one of my button but no effect. it still produce sound. tested on Google Nexus 10

Comment: the problem was with performClick() it doesn't respect the `setSoundEffectsEnabled(false)`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar The solution to that seems to use the xml attribute instead of do it programatically `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"`

Answer (score 46):

In case anyone wonders, here is the XML way:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

Comment: This works not even for button, also for other "clickable=true" views.

Answer (score 3):

For those who write code in Kotlin.

```
button.isSoundEffectsEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<Button
    ......
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"/>
```

Java code

```
button = findViewbyId(R.id.YourBUttonID);
button.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```