# Android: button plays 2 sounds onClick

Tags: android, button, audio, soundpool

I have a `GridView` with buttons. I have edited the `GridView.onItemClickLisener` to play a sound when a button is clicked:

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long arg3) {
                        Button button = (Button) view;
                        button.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY);
                        mSoundPoolHelper.play(mSoundId);
                    }
                });
```

However, when I click the buttons I can listen two different sounds. One is `mSoundId`, set up in the listener. But additionally, I can listen the Android default button click sound. If I turn down the media volume, then I can only listen to the Android default button click sound. How can I remove this sound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable the `Button` default click sound, then use the following code,

```
yourbutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Also you can disable default sound throughout your Application by changing in your theme.Refere below post for this,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763254/1564821

[Disable Button click sound in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293608/disable-button-click-sound-in-android)

Comment: That didn't work on the `Button` but it does when setting it to the `GridView`. Thanks