# Play random sound on button click

Tags: android, button, android-activity, soundpool

I want to my application play random sound when user click on button. So I don't want android natural sound, I want to play my own sound every time user click on one button. Does anyone knows the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To play a sound:

[Play sound on button click android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459122/play-sound-on-button-click-android)

For a random sound you just need to add all sounds in a list. 
And in the onClickListener just get a random sound from your list.
Something like this:

```
List<Integer> soundList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
soundList.add(R.raw.sound1);
soundList.add(R.raw.sound2);
soundList.add(R.raw.sound3);
soundList.add(R.raw.sound4);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener {
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        playRandomSound();
    }
});


private void playRandomSound() {
    int randomInt = (new Random().nextInt(soundList.size()));
    int sound = soundList.get(randomInt);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sound);
    mp.start();
}
```

No guarantee that this works! It's just an example, how you could do it!

Comment: Is there a way to disable natural sound of android click

Comment: is there any way to have it play all the songs randomly without halting the main activity?

Comment: What do you mean? Playing all songs by default in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that is:

1. Embed your sound , as an MP3 encoded file
2. Attaching a click event handler in the Android App

   myButtonTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   ```
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

          //code that runs when button is clicked

       }
   });
   ```
3. Access and play the embedded MP3 file from the application in the event handler

   MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(FakeCallScreen.this, R.raw.mysoundfile);
   mPlayer.start();

see
[How do I play an mp3 in the res/raw folder of my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162230/how-do-i-play-an-mp3-in-the-res-raw-folder-of-my-android-app)

A tutorial explaining a complete process

http://www.accelerated-ideas.com/news/android-app-development--how-to-add-and-play-music-and-audio-files.aspx

**Edit:**

To disable native android click sound

```
yourbutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

source :
 [Disable Button click sound in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293608/disable-button-click-sound-in-android)

Comment: I know how to play a sound, but is there a way to disable natural sound of click in android

Comment: see updated answer, google query used : "android api disable click sound"