# How can I set on the screen, the 'onClick' method 'setSoundEffectEnabled(false)'?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, touchscreen, android-studio-3.2

My ConstraintLayout has an OnClick method, so every time the screen is touched, i works like a button. But the problem here is that I need to get rid of the default sound button but the setSoundEffectEnabled(false)' ONLY works for actual button views.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Button click sound in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293608/disable-button-click-sound-in-android)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15293689/5502638, here is the answer, kindly search before posting question

Comment: the problem is that it is not a button view so that solution doesn´t work. Of course I search before posting any question I don´t want to waste your time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27683258/5502638, see comment, u might need to write clickable true at Constraint layout in xml