# Disable FlatButton sound on tap (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

Im making an app that play sounds when you press FlatButtons, and I want to disable the predetermined pop sound that plays every time you touch the screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

you cant disable the sound for the `flatbutton` .you can use `InkWell()` Widget it offers you the methode `enableFeedback` . you can set it as false and you should be alright

Answer (score 4):

Use **MaterialButton**. All the styling remains the same but you have the added benefit of implementing

```
enableFeedback: false,
```

which will remove the default click sound.

Comment: Good suggestion! Flatbutton is deprecated in Flutter 2. MaterialButton is the best substitute for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**FlatButton = TextButton** (in new Flutter)

```
TextButton(
style: ButtonStyle(
enableFeedback: false),
```

The same works with **ElevatedButton**

Answer (score 0):

One of the idea is to use `InkWell()` widget instead.

Refer: [How to mute the sound of buttons in application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549239/how-to-mute-the-sound-of-buttons-in-application)