# missing property enableFeedback for RaisedButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html), RaisedButton has a property "enableFeedback", which controls "Whether detected gestures should provide acoustic and/or haptic feedback".

I'm trying to set `enableFeedback: false` in my Androd app, but it appears that this property doesn't exist for RaisedButton. I'm  getting the following error: `Error: No named parameter with the name 'enableFeedback'.`

Is the documentation wrong?

What I want to do is to prevent my app to play a sound when a raised button is tapped (which it's doing right now).

edit:
[Workaround here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57585225/disable-flatbutton-sound-on-tap-flutter). Use MaterialButton instead of RaisedButton. MaterialButton has, indeed, a enableFeedback property. Not perfect, though, since RaisedButton has better default styling for my purposes (e.g. disabledColor).

Answer (score 0):

I checked github code for [RaisedButon](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/dev/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/raised_button.dart) and that control never had that property. The class that do have `enableFeedback` is `MaterialButton`, the parent class of `RaisedButon`, but setting that property is not available trough constructor so it keeps the default value of `true` and you can't change it.

So the documentation is correct.. the property exists trough inheritance, it's just that you can't change the value.

Answer (score 0):

**FlatButton = TextButton (in new Flutter)**

**RaisedButton = ElevatedButton (in new Flutter)**

```
TextButton(
style: ButtonStyle(
enableFeedback: false),
```

or

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
    enableFeedback: false),
```

Answer (score -1):

Please change RaisedButton to ElevatedButton and then try it.