Flutter disable button sounds without changing the button code
in my app I have a button and I want it to disable the sound effects in the app.
When i say sound effects I mean that default button click sound for every button in my app (there are many in many pages)
I do not want to manually conditionally set enableFeedback in each button.
I tried :
SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod('SystemSound.setEnabled', true);

but it doesn't seem to work.
I have no problem importing a package to do so if anyone knows the suitable one ..

have you checked this link

Does this answer your question? Is there a way to turn off the sound response when pressing a button for the entire flutter application?

Also, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549239/how-to-mute-the-sound-of-buttons-in-application

disabling in a theme is cannot be conditional to my understanding so it is not an option. Also the other option is about enableFeedback each button which doesn't sound like a good solution for apps with many buttons.
